# Why are $AB,AC,AN,AU,AV$ mapped to $IF,IE,IT,IP,IQ$ (IMO Shortlist 2019 G6)?

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

Source : Solution 3 of G6 in pg 71 of https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2019SL.pdf

Problem : Let $I$ be the incentre of acute-angled triangle ABC.  Let the incircle meet $BC, CA,$ and $AB$ at $D,E,$ and $F$, respectively.  Let the line $EF$ intersect the circumcircle of the triangle at P and Q such that $F$ lies between $E$ and $P$.  Prove that $\angle DPA+\angle AQD=\angle QIP$.

[image]

My questions : I understand everything until the last paragraph.  How is the combination of "these two transformations" a projective map from the lines $AB,AC,AN,AU,AV$ to $IF,IE,IT,IP,IQ$?  I'm also not sure why does this combination of maps preserve orthogonality when the solution says "On the other hand ..."?  Can you please help elaborate?

Using geogebra I tested the claim in the last paragraph to be true.  That is: if $G$ is a point on the line PQ.  Let $AG$ intersects $\Gamma$ (the circumcircle of ABC) again at $G_1$.  Let $G_2$ be the inversion of $G_1$ wrt the circle centred at $R$ with radius $RB$.  Then let $G'$ be the intersection of $AG_2$ with $PQ$.  Then $AG\perp IG'$.  I'm just not seeing why this is true from the last paragraph of the official soln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what is said in that last paragraph.  Basically, this is true :

Let $a,b,c,d$ be concurrent lines, and $a',b',c',d'$ be also concurrent lines. Suppose there exists a projectivity between $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a',b',c',d')$.  If $\measuredangle(a,a')=\measuredangle(b,b')=\measuredangle(c,c')=\theta$, then

(1) $\measuredangle(d,d')=\theta$

(2) $\measuredangle(s,t)=\measuredangle(s',t')$ for all $s,t\in\{a,b,c,d\}$.

Comment: Any progress with showing that the combination of the two transformations is a projective map from AB, AC, AN, AU, AV to IF, IE, IT, IP, IQ?

Comment: Specifically, how is point A suddenly mapped to point I?

Comment: @user75619  First, inversion about the circle with center $R$ is a projective map.   So $(B,C,N,U,V)$ and $(B,C,M,P,Q)$ are projectively equivalent.  But all these points are on the same circle $\Gamma$ which also contains $A$ so the pencils $(AB,AC,AN,AU,AV)$ and $(AB,AC,AM,AP,AQ)$ are projectively equivalent.    Then the projection from $A$ makes $(AB,AC,AN,AU,AV)$ and $(AB,AC,AM,AP,AQ)=(AF,AE,AT,AP,AQ)$ projectively equivalent.  Because $F,E,T,P,Q$ are collinear, $(AF,AE,AT,AP,AQ)$ and $(IF,IE,IT,IP,IQ)$ are projectively equivalent.

Comment: Therefore $(AB,AC,AN,AU,AV)$ and $(IF,IE,IT,IP,IQ)$ are projectively equivalent.  But from the statement in my answer above, $AB\perp IF$, $AC\perp IE$, $AN\perp AT$ mean that the remaining pairs of lines are orthogonal: $AU\perp IP$ and $AV\perp IQ$.  Sorry for late reply btw.  I was on vacation.